# g++ automatically imports libkernel32.a and libuser32.a?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, g++

I'm just wondering about something regarding compiling windows programs under g++.
Let's say I have a (very) simple program:

```
int __stdcall WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    char* szCmdLine,
    int iCmdShow)
{
    registerWindowClass(hInstance);
    HWND hwnd = createWindow(hInstance);

    MSG msg;
    bool iRet;
    while((iRet = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) != 0){
        if(iRet == -1)
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;

}
```

where the functions

```
registerWindowClass
createWindow
```

do exactly what their names suggest. The window procedure for the registered window class is implemented just to handle the WM_DESTROY message by calling PostQuitMessage(0);

I compile this as

```
g++ -o test.exe test.cpp -lgdi32
```

Here I'm required to link with the import library libgdi32.a, otherwise I get an undefined reference to the function GetStockObject, which I use for setting
the window class' background brush handle.

Now, from what I understand much of the basic functionality of windows programs are contained in the libraries kernel32.dll, user32.dll. For example, user32.dll contains functions for dealing with user input. Therefore, I assume these libraries are indeed used in my simple program? However, note that I do **not** have to explicitly link against their import libraries. I did not compile as this:

```
g++ -o test.exe test.cpp -lgdi32 -lkernel32 -luser32
```

Why aren't I requierd to link against libkernel32.a and libuser32.a, but I am required to link against libgdi32.a?

If we create a Visual Studio project and go to
Project Properties -> Linker -> Input
and look at Additional Dependencies we can clearly see kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;comdlg32,...etc.

[image: Visual Studio - Additional Dependencies]

My own "guess" at the answer is the following (which might be completely wrong):
My code explicitly calls a function in gdi32.dll, but it doesn't explicitly call any functions in kernel32.dll or user32.dll. Instead, Windows itself performs a bunch of calls to kernel32.dll and user32.dll "under the hood". Since I do not use any of the functions in kernel32.dll or user32.dll in my program I do not have to link against them either.
I might be completely wrong...

Thanks for any input.

Comment: You are guessing wrong. [GetMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936.aspx), for example, is a *user32.dll* export. And you are explicitly calling that.

Comment: Okay, thanks, that rules out my guess :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, your assumption is a bit wrong. Linking against something does not actually mean that it is needed. Visual Studio has the default library set just to protect you from having to resolve the linker issues yourself and look up which library contains which function on MSDN. Let's take a look at a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If we compile this in VS2012 with the all the default libraries (same as in your screenshot)

[image]

and take a look on the generated .exe file with depends.exe we see that only `kernel32.dll` is really loaded

[image]

it is visible that the number of imports is quite low.

As for your comment about "under the hood" - if something is being used "under the hood" then that library links to `kernel32.dll` or whatever, not you yourself. If you make a closer inspection with depends.exe you'll see that `msvcp110d.dll` for example also is linked with `kernel32.lib` (also visible in the screenshot). That being said, there is of course the stub init routine that calls your `main`, that also uses something and that stuff must be linked in by your binary (and the default libraries take care of that).

So, the real question here is - what is the minimum set of libraries that Visual Studio and g++ consider to be needed by an average program. Well, my personal opinion is that you will quite rarely need GDI, so no problem with not having it by default.

Comment: Okay, so do I understand you correctly when I say this:    g++ -o test.exe test.cpp is "equivalent" to g++ -o test.exe test.cpp -lkernel32 -luser32, because libkernel32.a and libuser32.a are always linked?

Comment: In general no, in your case yes. The default libraries used by gcc/g++ depend on how it was built/configured. What you can do is add `-v` to your build line like `gcc -v <all your other stuff>` and that will dump the full commands used by gcc so you will be able to see what is there by default.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good hint. I tried compiling with the flag '-v' and in the variable COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS I can see (among many other things) -luser32 -lkernel32.